# Exclude subdomain from SSL mod_rewrite rule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Kind of racking my brain on this one.  I'm using mod_rewrite to switch non-https requests to https.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}  !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path/file.htm$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^devel\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [last,redirect=301]
```

It works as expected except my devel site isn't being excluded from the SSL rewrite rule (devel.example.com gets rewritten to www.example.com).  The condition above it (REQUEST_URI) works fine.  This is all set in my site file under the VirtualHost setup.

Comment: Are there any other rules in your htaccess or server config?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a Coldfusion Application variable gone a muck combined with some cacheing issues.